# Build system for a VISUAL STUDIO 2008' C++ project

Tags: visual-c++

i'am developing a rigid body simulation (physics) in my workstation and i need to share this project with teachers from my university. The problem is the workstations of my teachers have different configurations about the path of some libraries. How i can externalize the paths on a VS2008 C++ project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to have everyone set an environment variable like `LIBNAME_ROOT` that points to the root of their installation of the library, and then add paths like `$(LIBNAME_ROOT)\include` and `$(LIBNAME_ROOT)\lib` to your project's compiler and linker settings, respectively.